# Appium Inspector Screenshot request get 500 iOS

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am using appium inspector to observe the application. The device connects and opens the application, but the screen view does not come to the appium inspector.

Log:

```
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 500: {"value":{"error":"unable to capture screen","message":"A screen capture was made impossible","traceback":""},"sessionId":"****"}
[W3C] Matched W3C error code 'unable to capture screen' to UnableToCaptureScreen
[MJSONWP (d6fad614)] Encountered internal error running command: UnableToCaptureScreen: A screen capture was made impossible
[MJSONWP (d6fad614)]     at errorFromW3CJsonCode (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:780:25)
[MJSONWP (d6fad614)]     at ProxyRequestError.getActualError (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:663:14)
[MJSONWP (d6fad614)]     at JWProxy.command (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/jsonwp-proxy/proxy.js:272:19)
[MJSONWP (d6fad614)]     at runMicrotasks ()
[MJSONWP (d6fad614)]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/d6fad614-7a19-4f8b-9d29-253efba8e751/screenshot 500 1035
```

Comment: 500 is the error code for an internal server error; a catch-all. Hopefully someone recognizes the stacktrace.

Comment: Sometimes apps are secured, for instance creditcard of banking apps. So you are not always able to capture a screenshot. Are you sure the app is free from any security?